# Java Memory usage continuously growing till OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, mysql, out-of-memory, heap-memory, visualvm

I have a program which parses files and stores the data in a mysql-Database.
My Problem is that the Heap space(I use VisualVM to follow them) is growing.
And the Memory usage(ps aux --sort -rss) is also growing.

When the HeapSize reaches the MaxHeapsize of ~128 MB I get an OutOfMemory-Exception.

How can I determine which data this is? Or what is not dealocated?

[image: heap size]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a memory trace by using the memory profiler in VisualVM.

A simple way to do a memory profile is to run

```
jmap -histo:live {pid} | head
```

If you are using SQL, the most likely cause of a memory leak is failing to clean up your JDBC resources.  I suggest you make sure you close off your Statements and ResultSets.

Comment: I just use a single preparedStatement which ins an Insert, so no ResultSet. I actually didn't close it propperly. But I set it to null, can andybody explain why this is not enough?

Comment: What peter suggested below is a very possible reason. Just to add, there might be many other reasons though. Did you close the input/output streams properly? Are you using a String to store large amount of data and modifying the same string in a loop?

Comment: @user2071938 the JDBC driver holds on to the PreparedStatement until you call `close()` on it.  This is needed as the object is a proxy for a native resource in some drivers.  Setting a field to `null` is rarely useful.

Comment: Thank you! the simple "statement.close" did it!
I camz accross the jmap command before, but the only thing I could see was that [B and [I is growing in size. But how could I identify the memory leake out of this information?

Comment: @user2071938 look further down the list at the number of PreparedStatements after a gc ie. `-histo:live` as you know the number should be at most 1.  note: if you use a profiler like YourKit, it will find this sort of bug pretty quickly and it even has custom probes for JDBC as it is a common source of error.